# How to reduce vulnerability to cyber attacks from injection?

Tags: sql, security, pyodbc, sql-injection

I have very little knowledge about SQL injection, and there are probably other threats I am unaware of out there for stealing company data, how would I make this python code better in regards to security?

```
merge_query = """
MERGE INTO sql_table_name AS Target
USING (
    VALUES {}
) AS Source (transaction_year, month_num, month_name, price_nt)
ON Target.transaction_year = Source.transaction_year 
AND Target.month_num = Source.month_num
WHEN MATCHED AND (Target.month_name != Source.month_name OR Target.price_nt != Source.price_nt) THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.month_name = Source.month_name, Target.price_nt = Source.price_nt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (transaction_year, month_num, month_name, price_nt) VALUES (Source.transaction_year, Source.month_num, Source.month_name, Source.price_nt);
""".format(','.join(['(?,?,?,?)' for _ in range(len(data))]))

params = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]

try:
    obj_crsr.execute(merge_query, params)

except Exception as e:
    obj_crsr.rollback()
    print(e)
    print("Transaction rolled back")

else:
    obj_cnxn.commit()
    obj_crsr.close()
    obj_cnxn.close()
```

This python code is given data in the following format:

```
[(2023, M12,    December,   541.44),
(2023,  M11,    November,   486.64),
(2023,  M10,    October,    468.23),
(2023,  M09,    September,  478.80),
(2023,  M08,    August,     475.41)]
```

And then is converted to a list in the *params* variable.  That data looks like this:

```
['2023', 'M12', 'December', '541.442', '2023', 'M11', 'November', '486.639', '2023', 'M10', 'October', '468.226', '2023', 'M09', 'September', '478.802', '2023', 'M08', 'August', '475.411']
```

This is the only method I have found to work when trying to merge data into an existing table using PYODBC.  I have heard of parameterizing the query or naming sql variables, but I don't know how to adapt existing examples/solution on stack overflow to my specific use case.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, this is t-sql on azure sql db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with your existing code as far as injection is concerned.**

Injection only happens when user data is injected directly into the query. Here, that is not happening. What is happening is that a dynamic list of `?` parameter markers are being injected, in a well-defined way (once per row), and the actual values are passed as a dynamic list of parameters. There is absolutely no scope for injection here.

**Be aware of a few points though:**

- Using such code does tend to focus minds on "oh just inject the data". Might be worth putting in a comment such as `only paramaters are injected here`.
- If there are no rows at all to insert then you get invalid code `( VALUES )`, so you should check for that.
- Dynamic numbers of parameters mean you get a recompile for every possible variation of parameters. This is not as many as would be had if you actually injected the data, but still a concern.
  A Table-Valued Parameter or a bulk insert into a temp table are therefore both better options than any of this, but neither are supported by pyodbc. `fast_executemany` or `to_sql` might be options, or `BULK INSERT` from an external file.
- The maximum number of parameters is 2100, you will hit performance issues well before that though.